# Explain spring boot hibernate sql query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing a basic employee management crud api using spring boot.
Below are the Entity and Service I want you to focus on.

I am trying to create this bidirectional relationship: `An employee belongs to a single department, a department has many employees`

employee/Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("employees")
    private Department department;
    ...
}
```

department/Department.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", targetEntity = Employee.class, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("department")
    private Set<Employee> employees;
    ...
}
```

department/DepartmentService.java

```
...

public Employee addEmployeeToDepartment(UUID id, UUID empId) {
        Employee emp = employeeRepository.findById(empId).orElseThrow(EmployeeNotFoundException::new);
        Department dept = departmentRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(DepartmentNotFoundException::new);
        emp.setDepartment(dept);
        return employeeRepository.save(emp);
}

...
```

**My question:**

When I try to add an employee to a new department the following queries run:

```
Hibernate: select e1_0.id,e1_0.address,e1_0.date_of_join,d1_0.id,d1_0.name,e1_0.email,e1_0.first_name,e1_0.last_name,e1_0.phone_number from employee e1_0 left join department d1_0 on d1_0.id=e1_0.department_id where e1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select d1_0.id,d1_0.name from department d1_0 where d1_0.id=?
Hibernate: update employee set address=?,date_of_join=?,department_id=?,email=?,first_name=?,last_name=?,phone_number=? where id=?
```

But when I try to add an employee to the same department the employee is currently in, this query run:

```
Hibernate: select e1_0.id,e1_0.address,e1_0.date_of_join,d1_0.id,d1_0.name,e1_0.email,e1_0.first_name,e1_0.last_name,e1_0.phone_number from employee e1_0 left join department d1_0 on d1_0.id=e1_0.department_id where e1_0.id=?
```

Can you explain how this is happening?
Maybe point me to relevant hibernate docs if required.

I expected 3 queries to run everytime:

```
fetch employee
fetch department
update employee
```

As I have written in the service. But from the logs it seems to not be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Employee` entity `department` field annotated to `@ManyToOne` is by default eagerly fetched. That is why you see the join clause when you try to get get an `Employee`.
And in your `Department` entity you have `@OneToMany` which has fetch type as lazy by default so no join, only plain old select-where without anything else from other tables.